# localhost:3000 not responding

Tags: node.js, express

I've just started learning node.js but when I try to launch the hello world code by writing on the terminal `node server.js`, **localhost:3000** gives me the following error:

```
This page isn’t working; 
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I've been searching for 2h now and I've found nothing. I've checked the port 3000 in **cmd** with `netstat -a -n -o` and it says that the port is listening (so I guess it is working). So what is preventing me from accesing to that port.

Here it my JS files:

**server.js:**

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port);
```

**app.js:**

```
const { request } = require('express');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'It works'
    });
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You never use `app` for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the required app to the createServer call:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

In this way the http server can route your http requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

Could process.env.PORT be set somewhere, causing your app to be hosted on that port instead?

An easy way to check would be to console.log the PORT variable in your script, and see if it has any value.

If it does have a value, trying going to localhost:PORT